# "Content-Type" shows Unexpected token in JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, smtp, zip, attachment, content-type

I am using SMTP for sending ZIP files from my ReactJS application.
I can send PNG images as atachments without specifiying any "Content-Type" as SMTP property.

But when I added `Content-Type : "application/octet-stream"` for sending zip files, it shows **Unexpected token at "-"**.

With what should I replace it to send zip files?

Here is my SMTP connection code;

```
sendEmail = (url, filename)=> {
      Email.send({
      Host: "smtp.gmail.com",

      Content-Type : "application/octet-stream",

      Username : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      Password : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      To : 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
      From : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      Subject : "Your file is ready! ",
      Body : "Body of the Email",
      Attachments : [
        {
            name : filename,
            path : url
        }]
      }).then(
        message => alert("Mail Sent")
      );
    }
```

This is what it render;
[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj7Ez.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace Content-Type to "Content-Type". Like this

```
Email.send({
      Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      "Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream",
      Username : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      Password : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      To : 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
      From : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      Subject : "Your file is ready! ",
      Body : "Body of the Email",
```

Comment: It cleared the error in parsing ( Thanks for that :-) ). But still it is not sending any emails conataining  zip file as attachment.  :-(